# Is one continuous partial derivative and other existing enough to imply diffrentiability of $R^2 \to R$ function

Tags: derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative, frechet-derivative

For $f: R^2 \to R$ to be diffrentiable in point $p = (p_x;p_y)$ it has to satisfy for aribitrary $\theta$

$$1)\space\space\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{f(p_x + rcos(\theta);p_y + rsin(\theta)) - f(p_x;p_y) - \cfrac{df}{dx}(p_x;p_y)rcos(\theta) - \cfrac{df}{dy}(p_x;p_y)rsin(\theta)}{r} = 0$$

We can estimate $f(p_x + rcos(\theta);p_y + rsin(\theta))$ using value $f(p_x;p_y)$ and partial derivatives of $f$ in a following way.

$$2)\space\space f(p_x + rcos(\theta);p_y + rsin(\theta)) = f(p_x;p_y)  + \frac{df}{dx}(p_x;p_y)rcos(\theta) + \frac{df}{dy}(p_x + rcos(\theta);p_y)rsin(\theta) + E_x + E_y$$ Where $E_x$ and $E_y$ are errors of approximation and based on definition of derivative $$\lim_{r \to 0}{\frac{E_x}{r}} =0 $$ and
$$\lim_{r \to 0}{\frac{E_y}{r}} =0 $$
Substituting 2 to 1 and I end up with
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{rsin(\theta)(\cfrac{df}{dy}(p_x+rcos(\theta);p_y)-\cfrac{df}{dy}(p_x;p_y))}{r} + \lim_{r \to 0}{\frac{E_x}{r}} + \lim_{r \to 0}{\frac{E_y}{r}}$$ Now if $\frac{df}{dy}$ is continuous at p the first limes is 0 and limit of whole expression is also 0 implying $f$ is frechet diffrentiable at p. However I only used continuity of one partial derivative (other just has to exist), while known theorem states that all partial derivatives should be continous to imply diffrentiability. Do I make a mistake somewhere along the way? It would be great if someone could provide couterexample of non diffrentiable function with one continous partial derivative. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not making a mistake

It is a general result that if $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ **has only $n-1$ continuous partial derivatives at $x \in \mathbb R^n$**, then $f$ is Fréchet differentiable at $x$. Unfortunately this stronger result is rarely mentioned in the litterature.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find this result in the internet and I was slowly going crazy looking for a mistake :)

Comment: The result is mentioned in the French book [Dérivation, intégration](https://www.amazon.fr/D%C3%A9rivation-int%C3%A9gration-Licence-master-Agr%C3%A9gation-ding%C3%A9nieurs/dp/270568350X/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=7YH14H8F37F8&dchild=1&keywords=claude+wagschal&qid=1631103925&sprefix=claude+wag%2Caps%2C165&sr=8-3) by Claude Wagschal. Excellent math book writer by the way, but not translated into English.

Comment: Apparently Apostol's book also has this version, according to [a previous question](/questions/2983956/) that I answered almost 3 years ago.